# How to merge three lines with correct start vertex

Tags: arcmap, vertices

I have a feature class with three lines intersected at one point. I'm trying to create equally spaced points along lines. I used "the Generate Points Along Lines " Tool which points will be placed from the begining of the feature.See image attached.
[image]
I have tried to split the lines at intersected point and flip them so they pointing in the same direction.And then I used the "Merge" tool. The point A was always calculated as start. But the point B is the start which I want.
What should I do?

Comment: To be clear, you want to start at point B,  then add points at equal intervals towards point A, then past and down the two branches after point A?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: This is not possible.  Create Points along Line

Comment: Is it possible to make the point B as the start not the point A?

Comment: You could make point B the start by cutting the line at B and ensuring that B was the start node.  You could confirm this by symbolizing with an arrow at the end of the line.  Still, the points would be generated down that line to the end.  You have a second geometry and that would also get points but from the start of that second line.  You could accomplish your goal but it would take some line cutting, editing, figuring out the remaining/remainder of the distance along the second line, more cutting, point generation, and merging of lines when all is said and done.